# Using data.table to create multiple columns with different condition

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create the below data:

```
           TRT01P numSubjectsFrequentEvents  numSubjectsSeriousEvents
1:    Drug a 25mg                          6                        3
2:    Drug a 75mg                          3                       NA
3:        Placebo                          5                        1
```

where `numSubjectsFrequentEvents` are unique subject counts with at least one `AEDECOD`,
and where `numSubjectsSeriousEvents` are unique subject counts with at least one `AEDECOD` with `AESER = "Y"`

the input data are as below:

```
              USUBJID         TRT01P                              AEDECOD  AESER
  1: xxxxxxxxxxx010001 Drug a 75mg  Diabetes mellitus inadequate control     N
  2: xxxxxxxxxxx010001 Drug a 75mg                 Hypercholesterolaemia     N
  3: xxxxxxxxxxx010001 Drug a 75mg               Injection site reaction     N
  4: xxxxxxxxxxx010001 Drug a 75mg                          Hypertension     N
  5: xxxxxxxxxxx010001 Drug a 75mg                 Rotator cuff syndrome     N
 ---                                                                            
125: xxxxxxxxxxx210003 Drug a 25mg                             Dysphonia     N
126: xxxxxxxxxxx210003 Drug a 25mg                             Skin mass     N
127: xxxxxxxxxxx210004 Drug a 75mg           Injection site inflammation     N
128: xxxxxxxxxxx210004 Drug a 75mg           Injection site inflammation     N
129: xxxxxxxxxxx210004 Drug a 75mg           Injection site inflammation     N
```

I know I could create two `data.table` and merge them, but I am looking for a way to make the data in one `data.table` step.

```
ae.freq <- adae[, .(numSubjectsFrequentEvents = uniqueN(USUBJID)), by = "TRT01P"]
ae.sae <- adae[AESER == "Y", .(numSubjectsSeriousEvents = uniqueN(USUBJID)), by = "TRT01P"]
freq <- merge(ae.freq, ae.sae, all.x = TRUE)
```

In real life, we might have a lot of columns with different conditions, so it would be great if we could avoid creating a lot of `data.table` and merging them.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution

```
adae[, .(numSubjectsFrequentEvents = uniqueN(USUBJID),
         numSubjectsSeriousEvents = .SD[AESER == "Y",uniqueN(USUBJID)]), by = "TRT01P"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- left_join(

df1 <-raw %>% 
  group_by(TRT01P,AEDECOD) %>% 
  summarize(count=length(AEDECOD)) %>% 
  mutate(numSubjectsFrequentEvents=ifelse(count>0,1,0)) %>% 
  group_by(TRT01P) %>% 
  summarize(numSubjectsFrequentEvents=sum(numSubjectsFrequentEvents))
,
df2 <-raw %>% 
  group_by(TRT01P,AEDECOD,AESER) %>% 
  summarize(count=length(AEDECOD)) %>%
  filter(AESER=="Y") %>% 
  mutate(numSubjectsSeriousEvents=ifelse(count>0,1,0)) %>% 
  group_by(TRT01P) %>% 
  summarize(numSubjectsSeriousEvents=sum(numSubjectsSeriousEvents)) 
,
by=c("TRT01P"))
```